# Get Laravel Authenticated User together with the user relationships

Tags: php, laravel

In my `User` Model i have

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jobs','job','id');
}
```

Now in my controller i have

```
return Auth::user()->with('jobs');
```

But am getting an error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
>   converted to string"

How do i get the authenticated user together with all related models.

Comment: Try: `return Auth::user()->with('jobs')->get();` OR `return Auth::user()->with('jobs')->first();` Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks @HirenGohel

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
return Auth::user()->with('jobs')->get();
```

OR

```
return Auth::user()->with('jobs')->first();
```

`->get();` and `->first();` will get you the data and then return it!

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
return Auth::user()->with('jobs')->get();
```

OR

```
$userJob = Auth::user()->with('jobs');

return $userJob;
```